# How to print the output of Spark?

Tags: python, matplotlib, printing, pyspark

I have a log file of Apache and I wanna to obtain the most visited web pages and then print the number of the visiting of the first 1000 most visited web page.

I do not know what is the output type of the spark library and the matplotlib library gives me error. 
Could you please help me how I can convert the type of the output and print the  related figure.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import random
from operator import add
from pyspark import SparkContext
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="WordCount")
    lines = sc.textFile("/home/globalscratch/wikipedia_small.txt")


    def getwords(line):
        words = line.split(" ")
        totalwords = 0
        out = []
        for word in words:
            if len(word) >= 1:
                out += [ word.lower() ]
        return out


    words = lines.flatMap(getwords)    
    wordse = words.map(lambda x : [x , 1]).reduceByKey(add)        
    s = wordse.map(lambda x : [x[1]]).sortBy(lambda x : x[0] , False)
    for i in s.take(1000):
        print (i)
plt.plot(s)
plt.show()

#stop Spark content                                                                                                                           
sc.stop()
```

Before the plot function it print's output is :

```
[1833572]

[951269] 

[745503]

[675384]

[555030]

[507073]

[261436]

[236230]

[225914]

[199161]

....
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
  s = wordse.map(lambda x : [x[1]]).sortBy(lambda x : x[0] , False)
```

your `map` function maps your RDD to counts only (because the word itself  was in the x[0]). Then the counts are sorted. Therefore, your output are counts.

For your purpose after the line

```
wordse = words.map(lambda x : [x , 1]).reduceByKey(add)
```

you need

```
for s in wordse.takeOrdered(1000, lambda x: -x[1]):
    print s
```

`lambda`-function here is a a custom comparator that will sort by value (that is by word count) in descending order (or, strictly speaking, by negative word count in ascending order)

Comment: With the current code I can print the list, I need to plot a figure and the error is there.

Comment: Could you then post  the output of `wordse.takeOrdered(10, lambda x: -x[1])` and specify which type of plot you want